# Word order and inverted subjects—should the pronoun have directly followed the verb in this sentence?

Tags: word-order

Ich lerne Deutsch an meiner Uni, und ich habe eine Frage über word order.

I wrote the following sentence for a practice oral exam in our class:

> Ich wollte heute Schnitzel essen, aber wir wohnen in den USA, **und deshalb hat die Mensa sie nicht gehabt.**

I was wondering if that last part is grammatically correct. What I wanted to say is "thus, the cafeteria did not have it," where "it" is "sie" (die Schnitzel).

I suspect I should have inverted the subject and instead written:

> ...und deshalb hat sie die Mensa nicht gehabt.

Would that have been the technically correct word order?

Danke!

Comment: You do realise that you are using _Schnitzel_ in plural here, yes? I'm wondering because of your use of (singular) _it_ in the English version, which is somewhat at odds with the (plural) _sie_ in your German translation.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused. I was under the impression that you can substitute the pronoun "sie" for feminine nouns (die Schnitzel).

Comment: AleksandrH, you can indeed. However, _Schnitzel_ is actually not feminine but neuter _(das Schnitzel)_, and the correct personal pronoun in accusative case singular is therefore _es_. Guess you may have been lucky here since _Schnitzel_ just so happens to be the accusative plural as well, and _sie_ just so happens to be the accusative plural for all genders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a native speaker both are perfectly understandable. The first one doesn't sound as good as the second one though. I've heard some other Germans use the first one. However I would stylistically prefer this solution:

> Ich wollte heute Schnitzel essen, aber da wir in den USA wohnen, gab es in der Mensa keine.

Bitteschön!

Comment: Yes, the use of *keine* usually sounds better if you can express it in english also with a negation and *any*, like in *thus, the cafeteria didn't have any*.

Answer (score 5):

> [...] deshalb hat sie die Mensa nicht gehabt

and

> [...] deshalb hat die Mensa sie nicht gehabt

are both correct.

The word order of "sie" and "die Mensa" doesn't matter in this case.

---

However the whole sentence sounds a little awkward.

> Ich wollte heute Schnitzel essen, aber wir wohnen in den USA und **deshalb gab es in der Mensa keins / keine.**

is what you would normally hear.

---

As far as word order is concerned, these two links might be of interest for you:

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/Pronomen.html)

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/Subjekt.html)